# applescript + shell script problem

Tags: macos, shell, find, applescript

I'm writing a script to keep track of missing frames in a render (thousands of image files). to find the numbered frames in the sequence I do this:

```
set thecontents to every paragraph of (do shell script
"while IFS= read -r -d '' file;
do echo \"$file\"|sed -E \"s|.*[^[:digit:]]0*([[:digit:]]+)\\..*|\\1|\" ;
done< <(find \"" & thefolderPPath & "\" -name \"*.*\" -print0)")
```

find finds all the files, and sed strips everything but the trailing number off them - it matches the numbers when the file are numbered like foo_001.bar (or even if they're foo3_001.bar) it looks for a non digit, followed by a series of digits, followed by a dot extension, and chucks away everything but the digits.

It works in the shell, if I run it like this (without the escapes)

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do echo "$file"|sed -E "s:.*[^[:digit:]]0*([[:digit:]]+)\..*:\1:" 
done < <(find "/Volumes/foo/imagesequence/" -name "*.*" -print0)
```

it produces a nice list of numbers, but in Applescript I get

> "sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near
>   unexpected token `<'

Any ideas? I can implement it with applescript by breaking the sed function and the find function into separate shell scripts, but that's way slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using `bash` process substitution here:

```
<(find "/Volumes/foo/imagesequence/" -name "*.*" -print0)
```

The AppleScript `do shell script` command always uses `/bin/sh` (`Posix` shell semantics) and process substitution is not supported in `Posix /bin/sh`.  Either rewrite the script to avoid `Bash`-isms or follow the suggestions [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html) on how to run an AppleScript shell script with another shell.

Comment: Well who'd a thunk it? Thanks.